# Passing a Collection of Java Beans as DataSource to Jasper, How to design this in ireports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to design a report, that displays the data from a collection(Say List). This list contains multiple POJOs.

The POJOs are populated by the data access layer of the application. How do I design a report template for this requirement in iReports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! Found the answer. The steps are as below.

1. Compile the bean classes and create a JAR file. This needs to have the complete package
2. Add this jar to the LIB folder in ireports
3. Create a factory/wrapper class that has a createBeanCollection method that populates a collection
4. Use this class's top level package as the class path in ireports
5. Use this class as the JavaBean datasource with the method.

Once all this is done, create a report with the new datasource and in report query, give the FQN on the Java bean and add the desired field.

Comment: can you please elaborate step 3

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JRBeanCollectionDataSource`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) for your report.

Comment: Shouldn't I use JavaBean set datasource?

Comment: for a collection of beans, this is the one to use :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BankDetailsList list = new BankDetailsList();       
ArrayList<BankDetails> lst = list.getDataBeanList();        
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lst);
```

Here BankDetails is a POJO

```
public class BankDetails {

    public String bank_name;
    public Account account;
    public String custodian_account;
    public String custodian_name;
    public String agreement_type;
    public double exposure;
    public double collateral;
    public double independant_amount;
        public double net_exposure;

    BankDetails(String b_name, Account acc, String cust_account,
        String cust_name, String agr_type, double expo, double collat,
        double independant_amt, double net_exp) {

        this.bank_name = b_name;
        this.account = acc;
        this.custodian_account = cust_account;
        this.custodian_name = cust_name;
        this.agreement_type = agr_type;
        this.exposure = expo;
        this.collateral = collat;
        this.independant_amount = independant_amt;
        this.net_exposure = net_exp;
    }

    public String getBank_name() {
        return bank_name;
    }
    public void setBank_name(String bank_name) {
        this.bank_name = bank_name;
    }
    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }
    public String getCustodian_account() {
        return custodian_account;
    }
    public void setCustodian_account(String custodian_account) {
        this.custodian_account = custodian_account;
    }
    public String getCustodian_name() {
        return custodian_name;
    }
    public void setCustodian_name(String custodian_name) {
        this.custodian_name = custodian_name;
    }
    public String getAgreement_type() {
        return agreement_type;
    }
    public void setAgreement_type(String agreement_type) {
        this.agreement_type = agreement_type;
    }
    public double getExposure() {
        return exposure;
    }
    public void setExposure(double exposure) {
        this.exposure = exposure;
    }
    public double getCollateral() {
        return collateral;
    }
    public void setCollateral(double collateral) {
        this.collateral = collateral;
    }
    public double getIndependant_amount() {
        return independant_amount;
    }
    public void setIndependant_amount(double independant_amount) {
        this.independant_amount = independant_amount;
    }
    public double getNet_exposure() {
        return net_exposure;
    }
    public void setNet_exposure(double net_exposure) {
        this.net_exposure = net_exposure;
    }
}
```

Account POJO:

```
public class Account {

    public int account_id;
    public String account_name;

    Account(int acc_id, String acc_name){
        this.account_id = acc_id;
        this.account_name = acc_name;
    }

    public int getAccount_id() {
        return account_id;
    }

    public void setAccount_id(int account_id) {
        this.account_id = account_id;
    }

    public String getAccount_name() {
        return account_name;
    }

    public void setAccount_name(String account_name) {
        this.account_name = account_name;
    }
}
```